# Categorical equivalences vs. categories of simplices

Tags: homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, infinity-topos-theory

Let $j: K\to K′$ be a categorical equivalence of simplicial sets. By [HTT, Remark 2.1.4.11], we have a Quillen equivalence (with the covariant model structures)
$$
j_!:\mathsf{sSet}_{/K}\rightleftarrows\mathsf{sSet}_{/K'}:j^*.
$$
On the other hand, we have the functor $\mathbf{\Delta}\to\mathsf{sSet}, [n]\mapsto\Delta^n$, thus a functor $\mathbf{\Delta}_{/K}\to\mathbf{\Delta}_{/K'}$ on categories of simplices.

I want to know: is this functor also a categorical equivalence (i.e., equivalence of ordinary categories)?

The initial motivation for asking this is: we have $\operatorname{colim}((\mathbf{\Delta}_{/K})^{\rm op}\xrightarrow{*}\mathcal{S})\simeq\operatorname{colim}_{[n]\in\mathbf{\Delta}^{\rm op}}K_n$, viewing each $K_n$ as a discrete/$0$-truncated object in $\mathcal{S}$ (I think, by Bousfield-Kan). I want to see if this can also be identified with $\operatorname{colim}(K\xrightarrow{*}\mathcal{S})$ in a canonical way (in the $\infty$-category of spaces $\mathcal{S}$) so that $\operatorname{colim}_{[n]\in\mathbf{\Delta}^{\rm op}}K_n$ in $\mathcal{S}$ depends on $K$ only up to categorical equivalence, which I can confirm when $K$ is an $\infty$-category.

(* means constant functor with value *.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No it is not. But there is a replacement for this. There is another model of $\infty$-categories: marked simplicial sets. If $X$ is a simplicial set with a set of marked $1$-simplices $S$, the fibrant replacement of $(X,S)$ is a model of the localization by $S$ of the $\infty$-category corresponding to $X$ (as a mere simplicial set). There is always a canonical map $\tau_K:\Delta_{/K}\to K$ sending an $n$-simplex over $K$ to its value at $n$. We can mark those $1$-simplices of $\Delta_{/K}$ that are sent to the identites in $K$. Then the map  $\tau_K:\Delta_{/K}\to K$ is an equivalence in the model structure of marked simplicial sets (where the marked simplices in $K$ are the identities). By a 2 out of 3 property, a morphism of simplicial sets $K\to K'$ is a categorical equivalence if and only if the induced functor $\Delta_{/K}\to\Delta_{/K'}$ is a weak equivalence of marked simplicial sets. The main properties of the comparison map $\tau_K:\Delta_{/K}\to K$ needed to prove what I claim above are proved in [Kerodon](https://kerodon.net/tag/01NC) or in my book [Higher categories and homological algebra](https://cisinski.app.uni-regensburg.de/CatLR.pdf) (Prop. 7.3.15) for instance. The model structure on marked simplicial sets is discussed in HTT, of course.

Comment: Thanks Denis-Charles for your great answer! I'm not familiar with the model structure of marked simplicial sets, but I trust you. I'll check the references you give and to digest.

Comment: A follow-up question: would this lead to $\operatorname{colim}(K\xrightarrow{*}\mathcal{S})\not\simeq\operatorname{colim}_{[n]\in\mathbf{\Delta}^{\rm op}}K_n$ in $\mathcal{S}$, for a general simplicial set $K$ (if you know the answer)?

Comment: On the contrary! If $\mathcal S$ is the $\infty$-category of spaces, than for any simplicial set $K$, the weak homotopy type of $K$ is indeed the colimit in $\mathcal S$ of the constant diagram on $K$ with value the point. As any localization functor is both final and cofinal, what I explain in my answer implies this is the same as the colimit of the point indexed by the simplex category $\Delta_{/K}$. From there, one can deduced with a little more effort that this is the same as the colimit of the sets $K_n$'s.

Comment: Got it, so it turns out that $\operatorname{colim}_{[n]\in\mathbf{\Delta}^{\rm op}}K_n$ in $\mathcal{S}$ depends only on the weak homotopy type of $K$ (not just up categorical equivalence).

Answer (score 5):

Dénis-Charles Cisinski has given [an excellent big-picture answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451164/2273).  But to flesh out his answer to the question itself, **the functor $j/K : \Delta/K \to \Delta/K'$ will almost never be an equivalence of categories — in fact only when $j$ is an isomorphism.**  So any non-isomorphic equivalent categories give a counterexample to your question, e.g. $1$ and the “walking isomorphism”.

This is nothing specific to do with simplicial sets: generally for any map of presheaves $j : K \to K' : \newcommand{\C}{\textbf{C}} \C^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Set}$, it’s straightforward to check that if $j/\C : K/\C \to K'/\C$ is full, then $j$ is injective, and if $j/\C$ is essentially surjective, then $j$ is surjective.  So if $j/\C$ is an equivalence, then $j$ is an isomorphism.